# Problem migrating from web api 2 to .net 5 web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm migrating a midsize application built with asp.net web api 2 to .net 5 web api. The problem is that I have now refactored the controllers and found that the way that the parameters passed by the query string do not have the same behavior in the .net core for routes.

So my problem is that to be able to switch to .net 5 I need to keep these apis working as they are today, I am not able to change routes and parameters at this time. I have routes as in the example below and that return the error AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints:

```
// GET: api/<ValuesController>
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<string> GetAll()
{
    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}

// GET: api/<ValuesController>?message=world
[HttpGet]
public string GetMessage([FromQuery] string message)
{
    return $"Hello {message}";
}
```

This controller works with web api 2. I saw that there is a compatibility pack for migration but it was removed in .NET 5 (Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim). I even tried to use it but runtime errors occur when registering its use.

I would like to know if someone has been through this and managed to solve it successfully, I already researched a lot and the most I found was some people talking to use IActionConstraint but the examples I found were to define mandatory parameters, it didn't seem to fit my problem.

If anyone knows something that can put me in the direction of a solution I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can do it automatically, but you could do this:

```
private IActionResult GetAll()
{
    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetMessage([FromQuery] string message)
{
    if(message == null)
        return GetAll();
    return $"Hello {message}";
}
```

Comment: Hi @Neil,the problem is when I access some of the apis in .net 5. As our current project is web api 2 we were using the routes by naming convention, prefixing the method name with the HTTP verb (ex: GetMessage, PutMessage, PostMessage) , and the web api 2 was able to decide the route by the parameters of the methods, but this does not occur in the .net core and although the project is compiling normally after migrating to .net 5 several apis are having problems regarding routes, or not finding and returning HTTP 404 or returning AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints.

Comment: I get that, but the question is how to solve the multiple ambiguous matches, which I've answered haven't I?  For your other question (about auto detecting the verb), you will have to decorate with [HttpGet], [HttpPut] as appropriate.  You can also specify routes (either as part of the [HttpGet("route")] or with a separate attribute [Route("route")].

Comment: It may be ... but it would force me to change all of our controllers, as I said, it is not a small project and the idea was to migrate to .net 5 and then maybe start building an api version 2 of our application. I have more complex controllers than the example I showed and the goal would be to be able to keep functioning as it is in the web api 2.

Comment: If you are a looking for a quick fix, then I don't think there is one.  New major versions of frameworks sometimes come with breaking changes :-(   Adding one attribute to each public controller function can't be that arduous.

Comment: Actually the controllers refactor I already made, adding the attribute of the HTTP verb, the problem is that I have apis, for example, a GET api api/users?status=active and api/users?accessLevel=admin, which with web api 2 he can register the routes with these filters with query string and with .net 5, migrated with the ControllerBase and the verb attributes, he says that there is conflict between the routes. I know that there could be design changes in the api, but at the moment I cannot change all the apis that were already using this standard, I need the routes as they are today.

Comment: Your suggestion to put the if probably works, but I would have to change the logic of many apis, add parameter checking and call another method in the controller, if it were a small project it would be possible and doing that would not be possible at the moment